# How to access Formik form props using cypress in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-props, formik

I have a multi-page **Formik form** that I want to test using **cypress** in my ReactJ app. I want to validate that all the fields are correctly filled when user submits the form on final page.

I tried to mount the component that includes the formik form cy.mount(), it gave me this error "**Unexpected character '�'**". Also I tried assigning id to the formik form and then accessing it using the id in cy.get("#id").

**Commands used:**
cy.mount();

cy.get("#id")

Answer (score 2):

you can easily handle formik forms using [cypress-react-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-react-selector) by react component, props, and states. You don't need to set any custom attribute in your JSX, you can find out the elements in a way which more native to REACT.

You can just use custom command `cy.react`

```js
  before(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.waitForReact();
  });


  it('enter data into the fields', () => {
    cy.react('MyTextInput', { field: { name: 'email' } }).type(EMAILADDRESS);
    cy.react('MyTextInput', { field: { name: 'password' } }).type(PASSWORD);
  });
```

For a detailed Formik example, visit this [example-cypress-react-selector-formik](https://github.com/gregfenton/example-cypress-react-selector-formik)

Answer (score 1):

I am new to using Cypress but this is how I test formik components.

I apply a data-cy-.... to the component I'm testing.

```
<Form>  
 <Input stuff={} data-cy-form-input />
 <Button type="submit" data-cy-form-button>Submit</Button>
</Form>
```

A simplified form.spec.js

```
describe('Form', () => {
  it('visits', () => { cy.visit('/login') })

  it('focuses on input', () => { cy.focused().get('[data-cy-form-input]') })

  it('accepts input', () => { 
    const text = 'Test User'
    cy.get('[data-cy-form-input]').type(text).should('have.value', text)
  })

  it('submits value', () => {
    const text = 'Test User'
    cy.get('[data-cy-form-input]').type(text)
    cy.get('[data-cy-form-button]').click()
  })
}
```

It is simplified but hope it helps.